# Try to call Drawer when i click an Icon menu but its not working?

Tags: android, kotlin

In this project i used **ModalNavigationDrawer **.i defined a drawerState and scope , then i use them as parameter for Two Composable Methods(if im not saying it in correct way please tell me) .The first Composable method is DrawerMenu. then i used a Scaffold and put drawerState and scope for two parameter's of TopAppBar too(because in app you need click there) the program has no errors but when you click on the Menu Icon , it wont work. could you please tell me where is my mistake ?

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            ModalDrawerSheet {
                DrawerMenu(drawerState, scope)
            } }) {

    }
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { TopAppBar(drawerState,scope)}
    ) {contentPadding ->
        Column (modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**This is DrawerMenu Composable**

```
@Composable
fun DrawerMenu(drawerState: DrawerState, scope: CoroutineScope) {
    List(10) {
        Text(
            text = "item #$it",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(
                horizontal = 20.dp,
                vertical = 10.dp
            )
        )
    }
    IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ExitToApp, contentDescription = "Exit")
    }
}
```

**This is TopAppBar Composable**

```
fun TopAppBar(drawerState: DrawerState, scope: CoroutineScope) {
    Row (verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(color = Color.LightGray)){
        IconButton(onClick = {
            scope.launch {  drawerState.open()}
        }) {
            Image(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Menu,
                contentDescription = "Menu"
            )
        }
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(
                id = R.drawable.baseline_compare_arrows_24
            ),
            contentDescription = "Arrow"
        )
        IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Image(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart,
                contentDescription = "Shoping Cart"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake .

I moved **Scaffold** to inside of **ModalNavigationDrawer** curve Brackets:

```
ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            ModalDrawerSheet {
                DrawerMenu(drawerState = drawerState, scope = scope)
            }
        }) {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = { TopAppBar(drawerState = drawerState, scope = scope) }
        ) { contentPadding ->
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding))
            {
            }
        }
    }
```